# SQL Server - Create cartesian product from comma delimited column

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2019, cartesian

I need to turn

```
Key     Location
123456  UK,France,Italy
```

into

```
Key    Location
123456 UK
123456 France
123456 Italy
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry formatting went out of the window

Comment: SQl2018. I can split the location colum with split_string delimited by the comma, but I cant find a way of then joining the result back to the original key

Comment: I could use a cursor but that is absolutely the last resort

Comment: sql server 2019

Comment: I'm thinking I must use cross apply or something

Answer (score 2):

Typically, assuming SQL Server 2016 or better, this is:

```
SELECT t.[Key], Location = s.value
  FROM dbo.TableName AS t
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.Location, N',') AS s;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fa4ddae186020a944d6f00678ab8ab19)

If you're on < 2016 (or >= 2016 but < 130 compatibility level), you'll need to create a separate inline TVF to handle this (example forthcoming if necessary).

Comment: awsome stiff, I'll give that a go and come back to you..

Comment: or even stuff!!

Comment: Yes, super, I'' go through it and try and understand it! Thanks Aaron